# Auto-completion all text in Texstudio without shortcut

Tags: texstudio, auto-completion, shortcut

How to autocomplete regular text in Texstudio, not just mathematical text, and without using shortcuts?

Whenever I type 3 letters consecutively, I want the autocomplete window to appear. I don't want to keep pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> all time. In the Kate text editor, it's like this: when you start typing a word that has already been entered, it offers you completion automatically, and you just need to press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Welcome. Have you tried Kile?

Comment: @cfr It worked! Even the pollution problem I was having with the auxiliary files I managed to solve with it. It has the source code in parallel with the PDF visualization, just like in TexStudio. I will use Kile. Thank you very much!

Comment: Kile is basically Kate underneath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kile is the best choice for Kate-like functionality because it uses Kate-part underneath. In particular, Kile offers the feature you describe.